# Docker compose: sync host folder with container folder docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is the my compose file definition

```
cli:
      container_name: cli
      image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
      tty: true
      stdin_open: true
      environment:
        - GOPATH=/opt/gopath

      working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
      command: /bin/bash
      volumes:
          - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
          - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
          - ./artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
```

I want the local folder `chaincode` sync with the container path  `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode`

For that i've tried this command

```
docker run -v ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode hyperledger/fabric-tools
docker run -i -t -volumes-from hyperledger/fabric-tools bash
```

But this still gives empty directory in the container

Comment: Did the `docker run` command start a container? Should need a full path for that command (compose file doesn't). The compose file syntax looks like a deprecated v1 notation, you should upgrade to at least the v2 syntax. What kind of docker host are you on (linux, or docker desktop for $x) and please show the commands you are running to start containers, and the tests you run to verify empty directories, along with their output.

Comment: using docker desktop on mac yes the commands starts the container

Comment: Actually this configuration included in docker-compose file and simply using docker-compose up  to run the container

Comment: Just tested on 19.03.5: `$ docker run -v ./:/host --rm busybox sh` and got: 
`docker: Error response from daemon: create ./: "./" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.`

Comment: I can't help without seeing what commands you are running, what output they generate, showing the files on the host and lack of files inside the container. Please show your work since I can't see your screen.